# Can the same result be archieved with inline?

Tags: html, css, inline

Im wondering if the exact same result can be archieved with `inline` , or `inline-block` instead of `float` if so, how?

See the following code (taken from http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_float):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<header>
   <h1>City Gallery</h1>
</header>
  
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<article>
  <h1>London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</article>

<footer>Copyright © W3Schools.com</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if so, `inline` and `inline-block` propoerties aren't intended to do so. These values express display property, which says, that element should be placed inside the flow of text and behave either as this text inside, or maintain some blocky properties while still being aligned with text. Shouldn't be for sure used to structure the layout like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I can does not mean that you should. I would stick with the float rather than use my answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

header, footer {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    clear: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    max-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
   
nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<header>
   <h1>City Gallery</h1>
</header>
  </td></tr>
<tr><td>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</td><td>
<article>
  <h1>London</h1>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the  United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
  <p>Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
</article>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<footer>Copyright © W3Schools.com</footer>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without tables?